# Trouble with Normal Matrix and Point Lighting

Tags: lighting, normals, opentk

I'm having issues with lighting in my game. For some reason, no matter what I try, point lights appear to cut off halfway through the center of the light. I'm trying to render this light on a quad.

[image: Angle 1]

[image: Angle 2]

Setup:
All of the vertices of my quad have a normal of (0, 0, 1). I translate this quad, rotate 90 degrees along the y-axis (just as a test), rotate 90 degrees along the x-axis (so that it appears as a floor), then scale.

I compute my normal matrix inside my vertex shader currently via the following:

```
mat3 nMatrix = mat3(transpose(inverse(model)));
```

Then I determine the normal via the following:

```
lightNorm = nMatrix * aNormal;
```

I calculate the vertex position with the following:

```
verPos = vec4(aPosition, 1.0) * model;
```

Then in the fragment shader I do the following:

```
vec3 norm = normalize(lightNorm);
vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - verPos); // lightPos is the position of the light, unaffected by any matrices.
float diffuse = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0);
vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(diffuseLightColor, 1.0) * diff * inputDiffuse;
lightColor += diffuseColor;
```

What is strange, is once I remove the rotation along the y-axis, everything appears correctly:

[image: Corrected]

Note: I am using OpenTK. I've noticed some strange behavior with matrices in OpenTK, where multiplication order is flipped from many examples and demos online, so I'm wondering if that might have something to do with it.

I've tried multiplying by the view matrix (I might have not done this correctly), flipping multiplication order, etc, and none of that has seemed to work. I've also used a normal map instead of vertex normals and I get the same result.

Why is it, that when I rotate along the y-axis, my lighting appears to be "cutoff" right through the middle?

Comment: I notice you're using one multiplication order for your normal, and a different multiplication order for your position. Have you tried matching these?